solana\web3.js Connect Timeout Error , How to set up a proxy？
I am in China and cannot access the solana devnet chain directly. How do I configure 'Connection' to use a local proxy
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'), { commitment: 'confirmed'});

const feePayer = Keypair.fromSecretKey(
    bs58.decode("ekD6Sg9Df******A45ef")
  );

(async () => {
    console.log(clusterApiUrl('devnet'));
    console.log('Public Key:', feePayer.publicKey.toString());

    const airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
        feePayer.publicKey,
        LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, // 1 SOL = 1,000,000,000 Lamports
    );
    
    const balance = await connection.getBalance(feePayer.publicKey);
    console.log("balance (Lamports): ", balance);
})();



Resolved

npm install node-fetch @types/node-fetch https-proxy-agent
code

import fetch, { RequestInit, Response } from 'node-fetch';
import { HttpsProxyAgent } from 'https-proxy-agent';

// proxy
const proxyUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080';
const agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(proxyUrl);

async function fetchWithProxy(url: string, options?: RequestInit): Promise<Response> {
    const optionsWithAgent: RequestInit = {
        ...options,
        agent
    };
    return fetch(url, optionsWithAgent);
}

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'), { 
    fetch: fetchWithProxy as any
});

